Convert Unicode string to ChrW() format
Following the following reply:
text
I would like to have a VBA code to convert a short string written in Hebrew characters to ChrW() format.
A string of the entire Hebrew alphabet including a space at the end:
אבגדהוזחטיךכלםמןנסעףפצקרשת 

should look like this:
ChrW(1488) & ChrW(1489) & ChrW(1490) & ChrW(1491) & ChrW(1492) & ChrW(1493) & ChrW(1494) & ChrW(1495) & ChrW(1496) & ChrW(1497) & ChrW(1498) & ChrW(1499) & ChrW(1500) & ChrW(1501) & ChrW(1502) & ChrW(1503) & ChrW(1504) & ChrW(1505) & ChrW(1506) & ChrW(1507) & ChrW(1508) & ChrW(1510) & ChrW(1511) & ChrW(1512) & ChrW(1513) & ChrW(1514) & ChrW(32)


AscW is the function you are after

Store the value אבגדהוזחטיךכלםמןנסעףפצקרשת  in  cell and then reference it in code. Something like Shell "Explorer.exe c:\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value, vbNormalFocus

Unfortunately, This approach doesn't work. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I am looking for a code that will perform the conversion from a string in Hebrew to the ChrW() format. The String can be split into Characters, and each letter must run the AscW function ( @Storax recommendation), which I understand knows how to perform the conversion to the first letter in the String. Unfortunately, I'm a beginner and don't know how to do it in code. I would appreciate help.
